# babel-plugin-lodash webpack config isn't doing anything

Tags: javascript, webpack, lodash, babeljs

I'm a babel/webpack newbie and I was tasked to reduce the size of our Lodash bundle. I more or less get how to insert simple plugins and changes but for whatever reason the `babel-plugin-lodash` isn't responding the same way `lodash-webpack-plugin` is. I feel like I'm only a minor mistake away from getting this to work as expected.

I'm using babel version 7+ and Webpack version 4+

in webpack.config.js

```
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: [
              ["@babel/preset-env", { 
                "targets": { "node": 6 },
              }],
              "@babel/preset-react"
            ],
            plugins: [  
              ['styled-components', { displayName: true } ],
              'lodash'
            ]
          }
        }
      },
```

in .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": 6 } }],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "lodash",
    "transform-class-properties",
    ["styled-components", { "displayName": true }],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    [ "@babel/transform-runtime", { "regenerator": true }],

  ]

}
```

[Webpack Analyzer Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q83ai.png)